# movement without stopping on move_base goals

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have mobile robot, I use move_base. I have positions sequence on 2d map. I want robot to visit this positions and make photo for example, but I dont want him to stop in that points. Maybe just a little slowing down of speed.

The simplest idea is to make this points as goals for move_base. But here is the problem, that robot fully stops in this points and then going to the next goal.

What can I do with it? Do you have any ideas how to move robot with visiting points without stopping on them?

How am I supposed to solve this kind of problem? Writing my own script?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339249/movement-without-stopping-on-move_base-goals/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-12-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-12-05**:
How are you handling going to multiple points (waypoints)?

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-12-05**:
with using move_base goal, one after another

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A rather **ad-hoc** solution would be to write a script, that sends the next goal always shortly before the current goal is reached. This would be fairly universal and work with any planner that implements the basic `move_base` actionlib behaviours correctly.

But a **cleaner** solution would be to [write your own global planner plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS). To my knowledge there is no planner that supports that but I would be happy to learn otherwise.

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2019-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-12-05**:
I'm sure someone's written one, but I don't have an example to show. However I'd bringup up that you want to go to a bunch of waypoints with continuous velocity and positioning, there's very good motion planning techniques that respect midpoints.

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2020-01-14**:
for example, how can I add midpoints to navfn global planner?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can take a look at [follow_waypoints](http://wiki.ros.org/follow_waypoints), this can solve some of your troubles. Other question regarding how not to stop at waypoint, you can modify this package to publish new goal when in certain range of previous goal. Or you can modify a local_planner to not to stop, but reduce velocity when in certain radius of goal.

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2019-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1